# Changing foreground color binding of cells based on condition WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to change the default color of a cell to red based on if the value is over a set limit. Currently, what is happening is that I have a grid with a list of oils with a checkbox. When a checkbox for any particular oil is checked, that oil is added to another grid where I can manipulate its amount. For example, if I check 1 oil, its "UsagePercentage" becomes 100. If I check another, the percentages are updated to 50/50. From there, if I click a button to increment its value by 1, it will change to 66.6/33.3 and so on.

What Im trying to implement based on my code is that if the oil's UsagePercentage is more than the UsageLimit, change the foreground text to red, otherwise keep it LightGray. But when I run the program, the UsagePercentage text is black. I dont't understand why binding UsagePercentage works, but ForegroundColor doesn't.

**Oil.cs**

```
public float UsagePercentage
    {
        get { return mUsagePercentage; }
        set
        {
            mUsagePercentage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UsagePercentage");
        }
    }
```

**OilList.cs**

```
public void UpdateFormulaWeight()
    {
        float ftw = mOils.Sum(oil => oil.TotalWeight);
        mFormulaTotalWeight = ftw;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("UsagePercentage");

        foreach (Oil oil in mOils)
        {
            oil.UsagePercentage = (oil.TotalWeight / mFormulaTotalWeight) * 100f;

            if (oil.UsagePercentage > oil.UsageLimit)
                ForegroundColor = "Red";
            else
                ForegroundColor = "LightGray";

            NotifyPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UsagePercentage");               
        }
    }

private string ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return mForegroundColor; }
        set
        {
            mForegroundColor = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
        }
    }
```

**GrayToRed.cs**

```
public class GrayToRed : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;

        switch(input)
        {
            case "Red":
                return Brushes.Red;
            case "LightGray":
                return Brushes.LightGray;
            default:
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:GrayToRed x:Key="GrayToRed" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<!-- USAGE PERCENTAGE -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Formula %"  Binding="{Binding UsagePercentage,  StringFormat={}{0:F2}%}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="64">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundColor, Converter={StaticResource GrayToRed}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>

                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: There is a typo in `NotifyPropertyChanged("ForeGroundColor");` in the property setter. Better write `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ForegroundColor));`. Besides that, you should use `Brush` as the property type and assign `Brushes.LightGray` or `Brushes.Red`. Or use a binding converter that converts from string to Brush.

Comment: @Clemens If I use IValueConverter, how would I change the text based on the condition, since the value is always changing?

Comment: ForegroundColor should be a property of the Oil class, then call `oil.ForegroundColor = "Red";`

Comment: @Clemens ok that made it work